# Is is possible to create an app using swift 3.0 for non iOS 10 devices?

Tags: ios, swift3

Can I program an app using swift 3.0, but deploy it on something other than iOS 10, 9.3.4 for example, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it supports building and deploying of apps on previous versions. Then only thing you need to take care is setting the version you wish to support like this on XCode by going to your project settings.

Make sure you use the API's which are still valid for this deployment target by checking when they were available and deprecated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So I could release an app made with swift 3.0 and have it work for everyone using 9.3.4.

Comment: Yes, make sure you don't use the new API's available in new SDK. If you use it, add proper checks to make sure your application won't crash because of the API not available.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much. You've helped a lot